# jQuery - Changing the color of a specific table element

Tags: jquery, selection, tablecell

I have this table:

```
<table border=1 id="Table">
<tr> <th> Product </th> <th> Price </th> <th> Shop </th> </tr>
<tr> <td> Stuff1 </td> <td> 10$ </td> <td> Shop1 </td></tr>
<tr> <td> Stuff2 </td> <td> 0$ </td> <td> Shop2 </td></tr>
</table>
```

On which I try using the following jQuery code:

```
var cell = $("#Table").find("td")[4];
cell.css("background-color", "red");
```

`$("#Table").find("td")[4].innerHTML` gives me `Stuff2`. But I can't seem to change the css at all with jQuery or even use `html()`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var cell = $("#Table").find("td")[4];
```

gives you the DOM element at index `4` so it only has native DOM methods.

Change it to this to call jQuery methods:

```
var cell = $("#Table").find("td").eq(4);
```

or this:

```
var cell = $("#Table td").eq(4);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, answered within 5 minutes what my CS teachers can't answer within 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[]` extracts the DOM element so you cannot use .css() jquery method on it afterwards.

Use a selector:

```
var $cell = $("#Table").find("td:eq(4)"); // or $("#Table").find("td").eq(4);
$cell.css("background-color", "red");
```

Note: by convention, jquery variables should prefixed with `$`(like `$cell`) so they are easily as such.

Answer (score 0):

When using the array-notation you get no longer a jQuery-object, but the plain dom-node. What you need here is the :eq selector:

```
var cell = $("#Table").find("td:eq(4)");
cell.css("background-color", "red");
```

cf. http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/